# Ansible - "NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined"

Tags: python, linux, ansible

Getting this below error while trying to run ansible(version >2) with python 3.5.2

I have looked into the github issues terming it as resolved, but can't sort out what needs to be done. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16013

How to resolve this?

```
virtual@xxxxxxxxxx:~/ansible-spike> ansible all -m ping -vvv
    Using /home/virtual/ansible-spike/ansible.cfg as config file
    ERROR! Unexpected Exception: name 'urllib2' is not defined
    the full traceback was:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/ansible", line 92, in <module>
        exit_code = cli.run()
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/cli/adhoc.py", line 193, in run
        result = self._tqm.run(play)
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 202, in run
        self.load_callbacks()
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 171, in load_callbacks
        for callback_plugin in callback_loader.all(class_only=True):
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/plugins/__init__.py", line 368, in all
        self._module_cache[path] = self._load_module_source(name, path)
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/plugins/__init__.py", line 319, in _load_module_source
        module = imp.load_source(name, path, module_file)
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
        module = _load(spec)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/hipchat.py", line 32, in <module>
        from ansible.module_utils.urls import open_url
      File "/home/virtual/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/urls.py", line 330, in <module>
        if hasattr(httplib, 'HTTPSConnection') and hasattr(urllib2, 'HTTPSHandler'):
    NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ansible python API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansible/2.1.1.0) does not support Python 3. The PyPI page lists only 2.6 and 2.7 .

Comment: So, when i switch to python2.7.9 in pyenv, 

`pyenv: ansible: command not found

The ansible command exists in these Python versions:
  3.5.2
` So, do i need to install ansible under 2.7.9

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam: you need to install ansible. Enter your pyenv environment and run `pip install ansible`.

Answer (score 6):

Urllib2 is specific to Python v2.

Urllib2 documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html:

> The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3.0
>   named urllib.request and urllib.error.

I don't think Ansible is compatible with Python 3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is currently not able to run with `Python3`. That is also stated in the linked Github Issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
import urllib2
```

Instead, you can call the library as

```
import urllib.request
```

Then use it like

```
urllib.request.urlopen('your url goes here')
```

This should get rid of the error you are getting